# devDependencies "module not found" error

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json

I separated my dependencies between `devDependencies` and `dependencies`

```
{
  "name": "contenttype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

As you can see I have an `npm` script, but when I run `npm run dev`, I get the error

```
webpack module not found
```

Why is that? The webpack module is in my `devDependencies`, so why isn't it being recongnized?

Comment: webpack-dev-server is a separate package, have you tried adding it to your devDependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`